# Memory utilized never goes down using UIImage:imageWithContentsOfFile

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage

On my app i have several UIViewControllers to load multiple images on each one. Looking at the memory utilized i realized that the memory never goes down, as i present viewcontrollers and dimiss them, the memory always goes up. I started to search about and find out that the problem was the way i load images, the method i used was imageNamed:

```
UIImage *oneImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

So i changed the method to:

```
UIImage *oneImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"]];
```

But the memory stills the same way...

I am using ARC and before the dismiss of the uivicontroller i call:

```
oneImage = nil;
```

And the problem persist, any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure something else doesn't have a reference to the image? Perhaps a `UIImageView`? Use Instruments and see what is keeping a reference to the image.

Comment: I have a uiimageview per uiimage, how should i dealloc an uiimageview, just with nil?

Comment: No. All of this should be cleaned up when the view controller is dismissed. Most likely you have a retain cycle with the view controller so when you dismiss the view controller, it is not being deallocated which means none of its views and other resources are not deallocated either. Use Instruments and verify whether the view controller is still living after it is dismissed. If so, see what is keeping a reference to it. Try running Analyze in Xcode. A common problem is when using `self` in a block.

Comment: How are you so sure that memory that was allocated during `imageWithContentsOfFile:` is the memory that is pestering you? Did you see it in some instrument? (I think if you open extended detail allocations instrument, you can go to the exact line of code where allocation hapened). I also use the same functions as yours, and `image = nil` is all I do to release the memory, and it works without fail, every time.

Answer (score 0):

The image probably goes inside the autorelease pool. I never understood this clearly about ARC and autorelease pools. I thought they became useless in ARC, useful only if you are mixing with old code, but it's not. Sometimes ARC release the resources even if you are using a method that returns an autorelease object right out of the scope and sometimes not.  Use:

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"]];
```

There is an [interesting article](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/a-look-under-arcs-hood-episode-3/) about this topic from Matt Galloway.